# C#: DateTime - Going through a period of days?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, coding-style, days

I have a period of days and I want to go through it and execute the same code on each date.

**begin** and **end** are **DateTime** format with difference of a month at least

```
while ( !(begin.Equals(end)) )
        {
           ...some code here...              
           begin = begin.AddDays(1);
        }
```

1. I'm not sure if it automatically upgrades the Month value when the Day value reaches the end of an exact month(in exact year) - for example February doesn't have always the same amount of days so...
2. Is there a better/shorter/nicer way of increasing the date by one day?
   For example something like this: `begin.Day++`; or this: `begin++;` ?

I'm not used to C# yet so sorry for asking this lame question and thank you in advance for any answer.

Comment: What stopped you from trying it by yourself?

Comment: I'm not done with the inside code and I like trying out everything when I have all parts of code I want, even if it means I might have some problems in the first parts.. I'm silly I know. It just feels better to me to have more lines without knowing if they will be ok or not :| (being without errors and warning is good enough for me for start :D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Yes it does. All date arithmetic is handled correctly for you.

2) Yes there is. You can do:

```
var oneDay = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
...
begin += oneDay;
```

You could also use a `for` loop:

```
var oneDay = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

for (DateTime currentDay = begin; currentDay < end; currentDay += oneDay)
{
    // Some code here.
}
```

One final thing: If you want to be sure to ignore the time component, you can ensure that the time part of the begin and end dates is set to midnight as follows:

```
begin = begin.Date;
end   = end.Date;
```

Make sure you have your bounds correct. The loop goes while `currentDay < end` - but you might need `currentDay <= end` if your time range is inclusive rather than exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way (don't compare for equality, because hours may be different and the loop goes forever).

```
    while ( begin <= end )
    {
       ...some code here...              
       begin = begin.AddDays(1);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't think about time at all because I'm setting the date only there, so thank you for your point.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is correct and should work fine. And don't worry, the [AddDays method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) will automatically increment the month and the year when necessarry.

You can also use a for loop if you find it more readable:

```
for (DateTime date = startDate; date < endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: This will not work. Dates are immutable and AddDays returns a new instance

Comment: @adrianm thanks for the feedback. I've missed the assignment part at the end of the for loop declaration indeed. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, which I think is a little more succinct:

```
while (DateTime.Compare(begin, end) < 0)
{
    /* Some code here */
    begin = begin.AddDays(1);
}
```

The DateTime object knows how to increment months, years, etc. as appropriate, so you needn't worry about that.